# Why does this DropDownListFor element not selecting the model value?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

The value needed to be selected is confirmed to be exist in the list but does not give it as selected.

**_ApproverPartial.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, 
new SelectList(TempData["UserList"] as List<UserModel>, "Id", "DisplayName"), 
"Please Select", new { @class = "form-control mt-2", 
    id = "UserId-" + Model.BusinessSurveyId + "-" + Model.SectionId })
```

Using JavaScript to make the component select the value works as intended.

But cannot make work directly with the dropdownlistfor helper?

Answer (score 2):

The following code demonstrates how to create a collection of `SelectListItem` objects used to populate the drop-down list:

```
@{ 
    var model = TempData["UserList"] as List<UserModel>;

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.GetEnumerator().Current,
              model.Select(d =>
              {
                  return new SelectListItem() { Text = "UserId-" + d.BusinessSurveyId + "-" + d.SectionId, Value = d.UserId };
              }),
              null, new { @class = "form-control mt-2" })
}
```

It is reasonable to use the strongly typed view.
In a action method:

```cs
List<UserModel> model = /* populate the data model*/;
return View(model);
```

In the view:

```
@model IList<UserModel>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.GetEnumerator().Current,
               Model.Select(d =>
               {
                   return new SelectListItem() { Text = "UserId-" + d.BusinessSurveyId + "-" + d.SectionId, Value = d.UserId.ToString() };
               }),
               null, new { @class = "form-control mt-2" })
```